# Detectar si el dispositivo tiene conexión a internet

Tags: android-studio, alertdialog

Estoy intentando crear una función para que me detecte si el dispositivo que la ejecuta tiene conexión a internet, y que en caso negativo me saque un mensaje 
diciendo que no dispone de conexión a internet y que después de aceptar el mensaje me cierre directamente la aplicación.

Después de probar varios ejemplos que he encontrado en la red no consigo que me haga lo que realmente quiero, os explico, me he decantado por el siguiente ejemplo el cual utiliza un `AlertDialog`, me funciona bien el problema que tengo es que cuando le pongo la instrucción finish(); para cerrar la aplicación en caso de que no detecte la conexión no me muestra el `AlertDialog`, o mejor dicho, creo que me lo muestra pero no le da tiempo a que acepte el AlertDialog.

A ver si podéis indicarme cual es el mejor modo para que me cierre el programa pero después de aceptar el `AlertDialog`.

Aquí os dejo el código que estoy probando:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );

        ConnectivityManager con= (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService ( Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
        NetworkInfo networkInfo=con.getActiveNetworkInfo ();
        if (networkInfo !=null && networkInfo.isConnected ()){

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("OK");
            builder.setMessage("Tienes conexión a internet");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", null);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
            TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            dialog.show();

        }else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Error!!");
            builder.setMessage("No tienes conexión a internet");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", null);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
            TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            dialog.show();
            finish();

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes implementar el oyente que tiene el setPositiveButton [Leer documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs?hl=es-419) ejemplo:
 `builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Cerrar actividad
                    finish();
                }
            });`

Comment: OK, eso mismo acabo de probar, pero veo que aunque la aplicación se quita del primer plano me sigue apareciendo en la lista de tareas en ejecución, ahora mismo estoy buscando un método para cerrarla definitivamente. Gracias por comentar.

Comment: Si es >=21 puedes usar `finishAndRemoveTask();`

Comment: Es >= 16. Tambien observo que cuando me sale el AlertDialog si pulso fuera de el, desaparece la ventana del AlertDialog y se queda en el fondo del activity.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es precisamente lo que comentas,

> creo que me lo muestra pero no le da tiempo a que acepte el
>   AlertDialog.

se esta llamando directamente `finish()` cuando no hay conexión, debes definir un botón para aceptar salir ( `setPositiveButton()` ) y definir  un listener para llamar `finish()` en caso de ver el dialogo cuando no se tiene conexión.

Debes realizarlo de esta forma, puedes usar este método que hace uso de la clase `NetworkCapabiilities` :

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
           NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
            if (capabilities != null) {
                if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                    Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR");
                    return true;
                } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                    Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI");
                    return true;
                }  else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)){
                    Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    return false;

}
```

y usarlo de esta forma:

```
    if (isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())){ //Revisa si hay conexiòn.

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("OK");
        builder.setMessage("Tienes conexión a internet");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", null);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
        TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        dialog.show();

    }else { //No hay conexiòn a internet.
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Error!!");
        builder.setMessage("No tienes conexión a internet");

        TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();

                //***FINALIZA ACTIVITY!
                finish(); 

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }
```

Si no existe conexión, al dar clic en la opción "Aceptar" llamaría `finish()`, tendrás algo similar a :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]